# Find the area intersected by two circles with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm asked to solve the area of the region intersected by two circles on the xy-plane of the given functions `x^2 + y^2 = 1` and `x^2 + y^2 -2x = 0` (with a double integral in polar coordinates).

To my knowledge, double integrals are used to calculate a three-dimensional shape and neither of the two equations given to us is in three-dimensional. I tried transforming the equations into polar equations but since neither has a `z` variable, putting them under a double integral doesn't seem right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are working in the plane. There is no $z$ axis. Why should a double integral not be right? Calculating an area will be a double integral and a volume a triple integral

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I'm not really sure how a double integral is supposed to work on a plane when you need to find the area.

Comment: If you have a single integral, $\int_a^b \,dx$ it gives a length $(b-a)$. If you have a double integral $\iint_A\,dS$ it gives the area of $A$.

Comment: I think your confusion arises because you are used to single integrals representing area as they are weighted by a function. Would it help to note that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b\int_0^{f(x)}\,dy\,dx$? The latter is interpreted as integrating $y$ from the line $y=0$ to $y=f(x)$ and then integrating $x$ from $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

When sketched, there are two circles with radii

$$ \rho= 2 \cos \theta , r= 1 $$

which cut at $$ \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Twice the Area =

$$2\int_0^{\pi/3} \rho^2 d\theta- 2 \int_0^{\pi/3} 1^2 \; d \theta $$
EDIT1:

I understood from the question the orange region as required, you took the yellow region. The OP asked for region of intersection with scope for ambiguity. When computed for the yellow area I also obtain the same correct result as the others, shall not repeat the same calculation.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I do not understand how you got that integral expression and it does not give the result Lion Heart and I got.

Comment: Ok, :)  we are all  correct, they way we see it..

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solution without using integration

The circles have the equal radius,$r=1$, passing through centers of each other.

Intersection Area = $4 \times$ area of sector with $60^ {\circ}$ and $(r=1)-2\times$ equilateral triangle with length of side $(r=1)=4\times\frac{\pi}{6}-2\times \frac{\sqrt3}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Your parametrisations are
$$r^2 = 1\quad\text{and}\quad r^2 = 2r\cos \theta \implies r = 2 \cos \theta.$$
Looking at the first quadrant, the double integral is given by
$$\frac12A = \int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{1}rdr d\theta - \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{2\cos \theta}^{1}rdr d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi}{12}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}. $$
A picture will definitely help see what was going on with those two integrals. The first is the area of the first quadrant, the second the bit we need to take off.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was given using polar coordinates.  Just to double check and confirm the result, it is also easy to check in rectangular coordinates:

$$\int_{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
\int_{1-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dx\, dy
=\int_{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
\left[2{\sqrt{1-y^2}}-1\right]\, dy
=\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

[image]